# How to disable swipe to dismiss Android Custom Snack Bar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I'm using CustomSnackBar library from GITHUB ,

Check this: https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/CustomSnackBar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/takeoffandroid/customsnackbar/SnackBar.java

This is so usefull to customize my snackbar.

But I want to **disable swipe to dismiss** , I tried all answer's from satckoverflow but no luck still its allowing to swipe to dismiss . Kindly advise is there any way to disable swipe to dismiss this custom snack bar.

- Android Studio ver:2.1
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
- Design Lib : com.android.support:design:23.3.0

Thanks in advance,

Comment: When Snackbar placed on inside  **CoordinatorLayout**  layout able to Swipe,  'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout'

Comment: I found a culprit its **CoordinatorLayout** 
When Snackbar placed on inside  **CoordinatorLayout** then Snackbar Swipe to dismiss is auto enabled as default not able to disable,  
My Root layout is 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout' 
But if I use other layouts like _Relative,Linear_ layouts then Swipe to dismiss **Disabled** as default 
**Is there any way to disable Swipe to dismiss under CoordinatorLayout  ? **

Comment: **I found solution**
`snackbar.getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                snackbar.getView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);
                return true;
            }
        });`